# Display pdf file in listview thumbnail C# 2008

Tags: c#, .net

How to display the pdf files in the listview thumbnail.

I added the components in the tool box, adobe pdf reader.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like Windows Explorer? Use the [IExtractImage](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fbb761848(VS.85).aspx&ei=ga7SSs-ZA4jWtgOzkeHvCw&rct=j&q=IExtractImage+&usg=AFQjCNE1hJl98ZdrApmTupcKTnTDfw4f6w) interface for that.

Or if you have a PDF reader library, you could use that to render the pdf to a thumbnail bitmap and add that bitmap to the imagelist assoctated with a ListView.

Or you could use a component such as [FileView](http://www.ssware.com/fileview/fileview.htm) which shows thumbnails of files like Windows Explorer.